# Strip remaining string indicators from converting string representing a list back into a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, dictionary, data-manipulation

I have a listdict being read from a csv for a function used in a bootcamp lab limited to base functions and built in modules and libraries. I am making something that is akin to a set of flashcards.

`one_dict = [{'Question':'onevalue','Answers':['an_val','two_val','3rd_val'],'Correct Answer':'two_val'}]`

I am reading it in and need to add labels to the answers for the user to input
ex: [1]'an_val' [2] 'two_val'...etc
if user input was '1' that would then test 'an_val' to the key 'Correct Answer'

Right now I'm working on formatting the question answer combo to present to the user and am quite stuck.This function is inside a class the class doesn't do anything right now and has **init** set to pass. The user has to input the answers separated by commas so it has to account for all data types.

```
def return_q(self,one_dict):
        #takes a dictionary and looks for "Question" and "Answers" as keys
        #Answers should be list so index counter puts answers list into a dictionary
        #answers = 1:option 2:option 3:option for the purposes of user input
        q_retrive = one_dict[0]['Question']
        index = 0
        answer_dict = {}
        adict = one_dict[0]['Answers']
        1st print(adict)
        adict = adict[1:-1].split(',')
        2nd print(adict)
        for answer in adict:
            index +=1
            answer_dict[index] = answer
        return (q_retrive,answer_dict)
```

This successfully returns a list but there are two quotes that hang around in the first and trailing answers.
The second print will return this using our one_dict ["'an_val", 'two_val', "3rd_val'"]
the return will yield `('question', {1: "'an_val", 2: 'two_val', 4: "3rd_val'"})`

I've looked around and I've tried obviously the `adict[1:-1].split(',')` that I see on a lot of posts on here and elsewhere. I've also tried an simple if else loop to see if I could get something working.

```
 adict = adict[1:-1].split(',')
        print(adict)
        for answer in adict:
            if '"' in answer:
                answer.strip('"')
            elif "'" in adict:
                answer.strip("'")
            else:
                pass
            index +=1
            answer_dict[index] = answer
        return (q_retrive,answer_dict)
```

I've also tried eval() even though it is technically not safe

```
adict1 = one_dict[0]['Answers']
        print(adict1)                       #print the list pulled from the Answers key
        adict = eval(adict1)                #evaluate it
        print(adict)                        #print after evaluation
        print(adict1 == adict)              #is this the same thing?
```

that results in

```
['1,2,3,4']
['1,2,3,4']
False
```

Which is more than confusing.

I haven't messed with all of the options due to limitations on my schoolwork (mostly using other libraries and pandas and ast recs) but I feel like I'm missing something simple. If anyone can help me strip the last little quotes I'd be very appreciative.

Comment: What is `one_dict` related to `ex_listdict`? Is it the same?

Comment: yeah sorry. one_dict is just the function variable that needs to be passed through. For the examples I made an example dictionary. You can replace `one_dict` with `ex_listdict` I've edited it to reflect as such

Comment: According to the definition of `one_dict`, `one_dict[0]['Answers']` (and therefore temporarily `adict`) would be a list of three strings. Therefore `adict[1:-1]` would be a list of one string which doesn't have a `split` method. The first code snippet would fail with an exception.

Comment: [link](https://emalm.com/?v=_jCLP) feel free to pause to compare if you would like. As far as I can see this is the same code but its not impossible that it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

The built in [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) function will help with what you are trying to accomplish. It takes an iterable and returns a tuple containing a count (from start which defaults to 0) and the values obtained from iterating over iterable.

```py
from random import choice


questions = [
    {'Question':'onevalue','Answers':['an_val','two_val','3rd_val'],'Correct Answer':'two_val'},
    {'Question':'two_value','Answers':['an_val','two_val','3rd_val'],'Correct Answer':'two_val'},
    {'Question':'3value','Answers':['an_val','two_val','3rd_val'],'Correct Answer':'two_val'},
    ]


def return_q(one_dict):
    #takes a dictionary and looks for "Question" and "Answers" as keys
    #Answers should be list so index counter puts answers list into a dictionary
    #answers = 1:option 2:option 3:option for the purposes of user input
    question, answer = one_dict['Question'], one_dict['Correct Answer']
    answer_dict = dict(enumerate(one_dict['Answers'], start=1))
    # answer_dict = {1:'option', 2:'option', 3:'option'}
    return question, answer_dict, answer


def main():

    question, answer_dict, answer = return_q(choice(questions))
    
    print(f'Question: {question}?')
    for key, val in answer_dict.items(): print(f'{key:.>4}', val)
    user_input = int(input('\n>>>? '))     # need to be int to match answer_dict keys
    if answer_dict[user_input] == answer:  # match value in answer_dict agaist return_q answer
        print('Correct')
    else:
        print('Incorrect')


if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

output:

```
Question: onevalue?
...1 an_val
...2 two_val
...3 3rd_val

>>>? 2
Correct
```